# How to get real-time resource usage of a pod in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a service, which use k8s to start jupyter pod for each user. I need to provide a real-time resource usage of the jupyter pod when user query for it. I tried metrics-server and kubectl top. Their results are from cache and have about 1 minute delay. Is there any solution?

```
> kubectl version
```

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14",GitVersion:"v1.14.0",GitCommit:"641856db18352033a0d96dbc99153fa3b27298e5", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-25T15:53:57Z",GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
>   Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.6-aliyun.1", GitCommit:"8cb561c", GitTreeState:"", BuildDate:"2019-05-23T11:28:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc",Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: You can talk directly to the cadvisor API, but there's some metrics which only make sense in batched form so they are usually aggregated over some short period of time.

Comment: could you please add `kubectl version`?

Comment: @coderanger no: cAdvisor has been deprecated since [1.12](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68522) even still available, any solution implementing this should not be recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could query the kubelet stats endpoint:

```
curl --insecure https://<node url>:10250/stats/summary
```

you can also make the query more specific to pod/container

```
curl --insecure https://<node url>:10250/{namespace}/{podName}/{uid}/{containerName}
```

where `uid` is basically any string...

The part of the code for your version is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.14/pkg/kubelet/server/stats/handler.go#L123-L126)

Another tip: if your pod run as part of host network you could query `localhost` also and would need to assign a service account with access to it. The query would look like this:

```
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
curl https://localhost:10250/stats/summary --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

Comment: `http://node:10255/stats/summary` will return stats of full pods. I am not sure whether the performance is good enough. Is there api for single pod?

Comment: yes... check the [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/stats/handler.go#L128-L132)
you can use `http://node:10255/stats/{podName}/{containerName}`

Comment: @xpbug I have updated the answer with more details.

Comment: I tried following two requests, they response "no matching container".
```curl http://localhost:10255/stats/py17484279885885120/py17484279885885120```
```curl http://localhost:10255/stats/jupyter/py17484279885885120/464e363c-ee5c-11e9-a89b-00163e09f676/py17484279885885120```

My pod yaml file likes `kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: py17484279885885120
  namespace: jupyter
  labels:
    app: py17484279885885120
spec:
  containers:
    - image: xxxxxx
      name: py17484279885885120`

Comment: when you run the `summary`, do you see your pod listed as part of the response?

Comment: Yes, I can see it. `{
    "podRef": {
     "name": "py17484279885885120",
     "namespace": "jupyter",
     "uid": "e0056f1a-ef0f-11e9-a89b-00163e09f676"
    },
    "startTime": "2019-10-15T05:51:47Z",
    "containers": [
     {
      "name": "py17484279885885120",
      "startTime": "2019-10-15T05:51:50Z"`
I restart the pod, so uuid is not like what i give in last post.

Comment: Tied again. I found following two requests works:
`http://localhost:10255/stats/jupyter/py17484279885885120/e0056f1a-ef0f-11e9-a89b-00163e09f676/py17484279885885120` and `http://localhost:10255/stats/jupyter/py17484279885885120/anyId/py17484279885885120`

Comment: awesome... I was actually under the impression that this uid could be anything... it's great that you confirmed that. Another key thing is the namespace as I believe it's considering the default one when nothing is passed.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. can you please accept the answer?

Comment: And if we don't want to pass token. we could use `http://<node url>:10255/....`

Comment: that's true when the read only port is enabled, but I believe the port 10255 is disabled by default on [higher versions of kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/732)

Comment: `curl --insecure https://<node url>:10250/{namespace}/{podName}/{uid}/{containerName}` also read stats from cache. The seems it collects stats asynchronously, and store in cache. It do the job about every 10 seconds. Can I make the interval shorter?